# string input and output in C

Tags: c, string

I have this snippet of the code:

```
char* receiveInput(){
    char *s;
    scanf("%s",s);

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = receiveInput();
    int length = strlen(str);

    printf("Your string is %s, length is %d\n", str, length);

    return 0;
}
```

I receive this output:

```
Your string is hellàÿ", length is 11
```

my input was:

```
helloworld!
```

can somebody explain why, and why this style of the coding is bad, thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`scanf` doesn't allocate memory for you.

You need to allocate memory for the variable passed to `scanf`.

You could do like this:

```
char* receiveInput(){
    char *s = (char*) malloc( 100 );
    scanf("%s",s);
    return s;
}
```

But warning:

1. the function that calls `receiveInput` will take the ownership of the returned memory: you'll have to `free(str)` after you print it in `main`. (Giving the ownership away in this way is usually not considered a good practice).

   An easy fix is getting the allocated memory as a parameter.
2. if the input string is longer than `99` (in my case) your program will suffer of buffer overflow (which is what it's already happening).

   An easy fix is to pass to `scanf` the length of your buffer:

   ```
   scanf("%99s",s);
   ```

A fixed code could be like this:

```
// s must be of at least 100 chars!!!
char* receiveInput( char *s ){
    scanf("%99s",s);
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    receiveInput( str );
    int length = strlen(str);

    printf("Your string is %s, length is %d\n", str, length);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also need stdlib include for malloc!

Comment: @fehergeri: yes, and stdio to use `scanf`. I guess headers have been omitted by purpose?

Comment: I'd prefer to make it `receiveInput(char *s, size_t len)` but then you'd need to jump through some hoops constructing the format string.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: agree with you. I wanted to let the OP understand how to avoid buffer overflows; now if he is interested in reading strings of a dynamic size he should be able to create the format string for `scanf`, or should ask it in a different question.

Comment: @peoro i just see that guy not an expert and says that not to forget a new include for the malloc.

Comment: if I don't want to suffer from the buffer overflow, what am I supposed to do? I don't know the size of my string.

Comment: @rookie: you need to pass to `scanf` a string whit the format `"%Ls"` where `L` is the length of your string (`100` in the example above). If `L` isn't known at compile time, but only at runtime, you'll need to create the string `"%Ls"` at runtime (eg: with `sprintf`) and then pass it to `scanf`. Note, anyway, that you cannot read as much as the user input: you need to choose a dimension for your string (eg: 32 characters), if the user then inputs more you'll lose some chars. But you shouldn't worry about this, if it's a problem to you, just use a very long buffer (eg: of `1024` chars).

Comment: @Peoro, should it be `100` or `99` ? Does `100` include the `\0` termination ? Also +1. This is great answer.

Comment: @Muggen, yes you're right. From `scanf` manual: _the maximum field width does not include this terminator_. Fixing...

Comment: You should also check the scanf() return value - say an EOF condition occurs, this will proceed to run `strlen()` on an uninitialised buffer, the print the random-length random-char content, possibly crashing the program.

Answer (score 21):

Several questions have addressed what you've done wrong and how to fix it, but you also said (emphasis mine):

> can somebody explain why, and **why this style of the coding is bad**

I think `scanf` is a terrible way to read input. It's inconsistent with `printf`, makes it easy to forget to check for errors, makes it hard to recover from errors, and is incompatable with ordinary (and easier to do correctly) read operations (like `fgets` and company).

First, note that the `"%s"` format will read only until it sees whitespace. Why whitespace? Why does `"%s"` print out an entire string, but reads in strings in such a limited capacity?

If you'd like to read in an entire line, as you may often be wont to do, `scanf` provides... with `"%[^\n]"`. What? What is that? When did this become Perl?

But the real problem is that neither of those are safe. They both freely overflow with no bounds checking. Want bounds checking? Okay, you got it: `"%10s"` (and `"%10[^\n]"` is starting to look even worse). That will only read 9 characters, and add a terminating nul-character automatically. So that's good... for when our array size *never needs to change*.

What if we want to pass the size of our array as an argument to `scanf`? `printf` can do this:

```
char string[] = "Hello, world!";
printf("%.*s\n", sizeof string, string); // prints whole message;
printf("%.*s\n", 6, string); // prints just "Hello,"
```

Want to do the same thing with `scanf`? Here's how:

```
static char tmp[/*bit twiddling to get the log10 of SIZE_MAX plus a few*/];
// if we did the math right we shouldn't need to use snprintf
snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%%%us", bufsize);
scanf(tmp, buffer);
```

That's right - `scanf` doesn't support the `"%.*s"` variable precision `printf` does, so to do dynamic bounds checking with `scanf` we have to *construct our own format string* in a temporary buffer. This is all kinds of bad, and even though it's actually safe here it will look like a really bad idea to anyone just dropping in.

Meanwhile, let's look at another world. Let's look at the world of `fgets`. Here's how we read in a line of data with `fgets`:

```
fgets(buffer, bufsize, stdin);
```

Infinitely less headache, no wasted processor time converting an integer precision into a string that will only be reparsed by the library back into an integer, and all the relevant elements are sitting there on *one line* for us to see how they work together.

Granted, this may not read an entire line. It will only read an entire line if the line is shorter than `bufsize - 1` characters. Here's how we can read an entire line:

```
char *readline(FILE *file)
{
    size_t size  = 80; // start off small
    size_t curr  = 0;
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    while(fgets(buffer + curr, size - curr, file))
      {
        if(strchr(buffer + curr, '\n')) return buffer; // success
        curr = size - 1;
        size *= 2;
        char *tmp = realloc(buffer, size);
        if(tmp == NULL) /* handle error */;
        buffer = tmp;
      }
    /* handle error */;
}
```

The `curr` variable is an optimization to prevent us from rechecking data we've already read, and is unnecessary (although useful as we read more data). We could even use the return value of `strchr` to strip off the ending `"\n"` character if you preferred.

Notice also that `size_t size = 80;` as a starting place is completely arbitrary. We could use 81, or 79, or 100, or add it as a user-supplied argument to the function. We could even add an `int (*inc)(int)` argument, and change `size *= 2;` to `size = inc(size);`, allowing the user to control how fast the array grows. These can be useful for efficiency, when reallocations get costly and boatloads of lines of data need to be read and processed.

We could write the same with `scanf`, but think of how many times we'd have to rewrite the format string. We could limit it to a constant increment, instead of the doubling (easily) implemented above, and never have to adjust the format string; we could give in and just store the number, do the math with as above, and use `snprintf` to convert it to a format string *every time we reallocate* so that `scanf` can convert it back to the same number; we could limit our growth and starting position in such a way that we can manually adjust the format string (say, just increment the digits), but this could get hairy after a while and may require recursion (!) to work cleanly.

Furthermore, it's hard to mix reading with `scanf` with reading with other functions. Why? Say you want to read an integer from a line, then read a string from the next line. You try this:

```
int i;
char buf[BUSIZE];
scanf("%i", &i);
fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, stdin);
```

That will read the "2" but then `fgets` will read an empty line because `scanf` didn't read the newline! Okay, take two:

```
...
scanf("%i\n", &i);
...
```

You think this eats up the newline, and it does - but it also eats up leading whitespace on the next line, because `scanf` can't tell the difference between newlines and other forms of whitespace. (Also, turns out you're writing a Python parser, and leading whitespace in lines is important.) To make this work, you have to call `getchar` or something to read in the newline and throw it away it:

```
...
scanf("%i", &i);
getchar();
...
```

Isn't that silly? What happens if you use `scanf` in a function, but don't call `getchar` because you don't know whether the next read is going to be `scanf` or something saner (or whether or not the next character is even going to be a newline)? Suddenly the best way to handle the situation seems to be to pick one or the other: do we use `scanf` exclusively and never have access to `fgets`-style full-control input, or do we use `fgets` exclusively and make it harder to perform complex parsing?

Actually, the answer is *we don't*. We use `fgets` (or non-`scanf` functions) exclusively, and when we need `scanf`-like functionality, *we just call `sscanf` on the strings!* We don't need to have `scanf` mucking up our filestreams unnecessarily! We can have all the precise control over our input we want and *still* get all the functionality of `scanf` formatting. And even if we couldn't, many `scanf` format options have near-direct corresponding functions in the standard library, like the infinitely more flexible `strtol` and `strtod` functions (and friends). Plus, `i = strtoumax(str, NULL)` for C99 sized integer types is a lot cleaner looking than `scanf("%" SCNuMAX, &i);`, and a lot safer (we can use that `strtoumax` line unchanged for smaller types and let the implicit conversion handle the extra bits, but with `scanf` we have to make a temporary `uintmax_t` to read into).

The moral of this story: avoid `scanf`. If you need the formatting it provides, and don't want to (or can't) do it (more efficiently) yourself, use `fgets` / `sscanf`.

Comment: +1 Bravo!!! This is a really really good explanation! Thank you! I hope the OP read it too :-)

Comment: I reread my monstrous blog-post-equivalent answer and realized that I made an omission, though I didn't know it at the time. `scanf("%u", &i)` _actually yields undefined behavior_ in the case of integer overflow, unlike `strtoul` which handles the error like any sane person would expect. Yet another reason to avoid `scanf` where possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first allocate memory to your s object in your receiveInput() method. Such as:

```
s = (char *)calloc(50, sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Why `calloc` when you're just going to write over it anyway?

Comment: I think sometimes a "string" in c is better to be allocated as an array just as a "secure" measure.

Comment: the choice of `calloc` vs `malloc` only affects whether the content is overwritten with 0s... nothing to do with one being an array.  I guess it's a bit like explicitly assigning variables an initial value even if you know you'll assign them another value a couple lines later with no read in between: a bit paranoid but vaguely reassuring if misleading, but in the case of calloc you can be sure the optimiser won't remove the unnecessary run-time initialisation.

Comment: @Tony: Thank you for your explanation but it does have to do with arrays. calloc() returns an array of objects while malloc returns one only object. Calloc can be a bit more versatile and well you may call it paranoid, but I prefer to be paranoid than to lament later. With a little explanation it won't really be misleading...

Comment: calloc() does accept a per-element size (in bytes) and a number of elements: you can expect the implementation to multiply the two and passes that value to malloc() then do a memset() to 0 or equivalent.  There is nothing inherently more "array"-ish about the returned memory than memory returned by malloc() - indeed, the pointer is later passed to free() and handled identically.  The clearing to 0-bit values is the only difference.  That said, if you are actually planning to use the memory for an array, and 0-bit values are a useful initial value for the actual type, it's nice.